# C# ExecuteNonQuery Error (Connecting My.ASP Web Form to an Access DB)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

I'm trying to connect my ASP.NET online registration form to  MS Access backend database. The connection code I'm using is

```
String connString;
connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Z\Desktop\Comp\MyWebsite\WorkDatabase.mdb";
OleDbConnection myConnection = new  OleDbConnection(connString);
myConnection.Open();
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO Parent([Username], [FirstName], [Surname], [Email], [Mobile], [Postcode], [Password]) values('" + Usernametb.Text + "','" + Firsttnametb.Text + "','" + Surnametb.Text + "','" + Emailtb.Text + "','" + Mobiletb.Text + "','" + Postcodetb.Text + "','" + Passwordtb.Text + "')";
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConnection.Close();

try
{
    using (myConnection)
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SuccReglbl.Text = "successful registration";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    SuccReglbl.Text = "Exception in DBHandler" + ex;
}
finally
{

}

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
{

}
myConnection.Close();
```

I keep getting an error when I click on the "Register" button. The error is

"ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."

I'm unsure how to fix this.

Comment: You put `myConnection` in a using block so it will be closed by the time you execute the command below the `finally` block.

Comment: @MethodMan Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: @Crowcoder can you give me an example of how I'd apply that code to mine? I'm quite inexperienced, sorry

Comment: it looks like you already know how to open a connection unless you have just copied code without understanding it.

Comment: @Crowcoder At first I did just copy it from an example I've seen to try and apply it to my work. I have a better understanding of how it works but I still don't fully understand it.

Comment: I can't really provide an answer because it is impossible to tell what you are trying to do. You are executing the same insert statement multiple times, with non query and  with reader. Maybe edit the question with what you are actually trying to do with this code.

Comment: @Crowcoder I am trying to link my online registration form to a table on my MS Access database. I want it so every time I click the register button ,it will take all the information I've put into the text box and applies it to the table in access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you said you are trying to, this is all the code you need.

Please be aware your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection because you are stuffing the user input directly into a query. A user can own your database or destroy it very easily. [See this for more information](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) and research `OleDbParameter`.

```
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO Parent([Username], [FirstName], [Surname], [Email], [Mobile], [Postcode], [Password]) values('" + Usernametb.Text + "','" + Firsttnametb.Text + "','" + Surnametb.Text + "','" + Emailtb.Text + "','" + Mobiletb.Text + "','" + Postcodetb.Text + "','" + Passwordtb.Text + "')";
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Z\Desktop\Comp\MyWebsite\WorkDatabase.mdb";
try
{
    using(OleDbConnection myConnection = new  OleDbConnection(connString))
    {
        using(OleDbCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            myCommand.CommandText = myQuery;
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommmand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SuccReglbl.Text = "successful registration";
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    SuccReglbl.Text = "Exception in DBHandler " + ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: I tried using this, and it was the first time that It actually worked successfully. But now when I try doing it again I keep getting an error on the label when I hit register saying either "Exception in DBHandler Overflow " or that the connection path is invalid. I'm unsure about what is causing this

Comment: More context is needed (and complete exception detail) to be able to guess what is wrong. Might be worth another question since it seems to be a different issue.

Comment: I would make a separate question if I knew how to structure the error I'm going through. I'll try to figure it out for now, but if I can't do anything then I'll ask another. I'm pretty sure it's to do with a connection.

Comment: Thank you very much, this segment of code allowed me to work through all the errors that I had! I no longer have an issue for this method! :)

Answer (score 0):

After executing the first query, you are closing the database connection. However, after the following try-catch block, you execute another query. And at this point, the connection has been closed.

I'd suggest to only close the database connection after all queries have been executed. This way you don't need a new connection for every single query.

**Update:**
I removed all closes' except the last one and the unnecessary using statements. This code should work fine:

```
String connString;
connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Z\Desktop\Comp\MyWebsite\WorkDatabase.mdb";
OleDbConnection myConnection = new  OleDbConnection(connString);
myConnection.Open();
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO Parent([Username], [FirstName], [Surname], [Email], [Mobile], [Postcode], [Password]) values('" + Usernametb.Text + "','" + Firsttnametb.Text + "','" + Surnametb.Text + "','" + Emailtb.Text + "','" + Mobiletb.Text + "','" + Postcodetb.Text + "','" + Passwordtb.Text + "')";
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

try
{
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SuccReglbl.Text = "successful registration";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    SuccReglbl.Text = "Exception in DBHandler" + ex;
}
finally
{

}

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
{

}
myConnection.Close();
```

Comment: When I remove the first connection close section It still gives me the same error. It says the error is in the line myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Where exactly is that? Because `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` is at least 4 times in your code as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

You closed the database connection twice. 
try to remove first myConnection.Close();

Comment: When I remove the first connection close section It still gives me the same error. It says the error is in the line

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @Zalgawi That is because a connection in a `using` block will Dispose the connection, and close it. This answer is not well thought out.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how I should structure it then? I'm trying to find tutorials but can't find anywhere that can successfully teach it

Answer (score 0):

@Jerodev
The latest version of my code is
String connString;
            connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Z\Desktop\MyWebsite\WorkDatabase.mdb";

```
        OleDbConnection myConnection = new
            OleDbConnection(connString);
        myConnection.Open();
        string myQuery = "INSERT INTO Parent([Username], [FirstName], [Surname], [Email], [Mobile], [Postcode], [Password]) values('" + Usernametb.Text + "','" + Firsttnametb.Text + "','" + Surnametb.Text + "','" + Emailtb.Text + "','" + Mobiletb.Text + "','" + Postcodetb.Text + "','" + Passwordtb.Text + "')";
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


        try
        {
            using (myConnection)

            {
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SuccReglbl.Text = "successful registration";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SuccReglbl.Text = "Exception in DBHandler" + ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }

         OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
         while (myReader.Read())
         {
         }
```

It is giving the same error but it is saying the error is in line 
"OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();"

Comment: @Jerodev Wasn't able to reply this as a direct reply,